# Rails Join With Association and Count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

So I have the following...

- **University** - has many providers
- **Provider** - belongs to university, and has many addresses through positions
- **Position** - belongs to provider and address
- **Address** - has many providers through positions

What I want is a list of universities with associated provider count
but the providers also need an address.

What I have tried:

```
@universities = University.joins(:providers).select('universities.id, universities.name, universities.slug, providers.id, count(providers.id) as count').group('universities.id').order('count').reverse
```

Provides a list like:

```
- id: 14
  name: Salus University
  slug: salus-university
  count: 72
- id: 22
  name: University of Florida
  slug: university-of-florida
  count: 45
```

The problem is the count includes providers with no address. So I tried the following:

```
@universities = University.joins(providers: :addresses).select('universities.id, universities.name, universities.slug, providers.id, count(providers.id) as count').group('universities.id').order('count').reverse
```

However, this gives me the count of the total number of addresses instead of providers with addresses:

```
- id: 14
  name: Salus University
  slug: salus-university
  count: 90
- id: 22
  name: University of Florida
  slug: university-of-florida
  count: 60
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to figure this out finally. I just joined with positions and added `distinct` to the count:

```
@universities = University.joins(providers: :positions).select('universities.id, universities.name, universities.slug, providers.id, count(distinct providers.id) as count').group('universities.id').order('count desc')
```